# Regards how to check memory leak in my web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Hai i am developing a web application with spring, hibernate and mysql. I would like to know weather there is any memory leak in my project because when there is many users login to my portal java utilization is maximum when users logout java memory is not getting released. Please suggest me any tool to check or give me any suggestion to resolve this problem.

Comment: Maybe connections still remain open??

Comment: Take a look at [JavaMelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) which requires a little effort but is easy, and it seems load testing is needed too: JMeter.

Comment: How to check weather a connection is still open?

Answer (score 1):

Memory Leak can be identified by collecting verbose gc logs. By adding the jvm argument -verbose:gc this will collect GC occupancy information. usually the output of this will be written in the native_stderr.log file or file where stderr has been redirected. Once the usage is over. Load the file in 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv/
This tool will help you in identification of leaks and GC behavior throughout the life span of the application.
Hope this will be helpful for you.